# String index out of range, converting String array to Char Array

Tags: java, arrays

So I am trying to convert a String array into a character array and I keep running into this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 16 . I even tried to increase my array size but that keeps happening.

The string that is in the file which is stored in the array is exactly 16 characters long. So that maybe the error?

"keyChar[i] += ht[j].charAt(i);" this line is where the error is being thrown. 
**UPDATED CODE:**

Now its working but only iterating through the 8 string and 128 characters.

```
public class Lab4 {
public static void print(Object printed) {
    System.out.print(printed);
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File dataSet = new File("data.txt");
    Scanner fileRead = new Scanner(dataSet);
    int index = 0;
    int tableSize = 128;
    String[] ht = new String[tableSize]; 

    int cCounter = 0;
    String key = "";

    while (fileRead.hasNextLine() && index < ht.length) {
        ht[index] = fileRead.nextLine();
        index++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < ht.length; i++) {
        cCounter += ht[i].length();

    }

    char[] keyChar = new char[cCounter];

    int charIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < ht.length; i++) {
        for  (int j = 0; j < ht[i].length(); j++) {
            keyChar[charIndex] = ht[i].charAt(j);
            charIndex++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ht.length; i++) {
        print(keyChar[i]);
    }
    //long HA = abs(keyChar[1]) + (abs(key[3] + key[4]) + abs(key[12] + key[13])) / 65535 + abs(key[15]);
    print(cCounter + " " + ht.length);

}
```

}

This is the content of the file:

```
1234567890123456
Aguirrie        
Alcantara       
Bhandari        
Carmona         
Casper          
Cook            
Daniels         
Nienberg        
Paschal         
Red             
Salkowski       
Zulfiqar        
Qamruddin       
Acevedo         
Ajose           
Arauza          
Buck            
Clark           
Crouch          
Davies          
Dugger          
Egbe            
Ellington       
Farral          
Garza           
Gurung          
Joseph          
Kelly           
Corey           
Adam            
Clayton         
Dustin          
Robert          
Kyle            
Scott           
Octavio         
Judy            
Derek           
Jeffrey         
Jordon          
Vinnela         
Lisa            
Todd            
Veronica        
Matthew         
Michael         
Akhila          
John            
Charles         
James           
Chris           
Wade            
Christopher     
Fernando        
Batbold         
Joel            
Fabulous        
Misogamist      
Maiden          
Eye             
Constriction    
Necromancer     
Syncopate       
Yolk            
Afterwards      
Person          
Northwest       
Irreversible    
Fabricate       
Honor           
Staple          
Under           
Jutty           
Finagle         
Cook            
Rush            
Wine            
Screen          
Perfect         
mole            
parasympathetic 
poison          
brutalize       
cap             
ratiocination   
cauldron        
prepossess      
wince           
orthodontist    
live            
magnetic        
inlet           
constrain       
marsupial       
rationalize     
scat            
toluene         
wet             
sparse          
quandary        
dactyl          
nosegay         
option          
forgetful       
privilege       
sponsor         
exhilarate      
guard           
noggin          
prologue        
seal            
seat            
tiller          
ichthyosaur     
lazy            
malfeasance     
compass         
diastase        
emperor         
history         
keep            
gangway         
labial          
sacrament       
taint           
withal          
oak             
preordain       
haberdasher     
crimp           
luculent        
pennywort       
prevalent       
monolith        
suffrage        
wiper           
zygote          
academy         
amputate        
brash           
consummation    
epicure         
indulgent       
minute          
job             
hypodermic      
meridian        
sinister        
tag             
uterus          
perennial       
humidity        
gynecology      
forego          
interchangeable 
needle          
reach           
urban           
nonunion        
jingle          
feculent        
deciduous       
channel         
decimate        
alarm           
perimeter       
unlucky         
wonderful       
script          
particularity   
mousse          
issue           
graduation      
neutrality      
proxy           
swine           
witticism       
parish          
sickly          
way             
periodic        
mail            
close           
bash            
conclusion      
drive           
foreclose       
habituation     
liberty         
pall            
recite          
empress         
impetuous       
ruminate        
fork            
horizon         
prerequisite    
romance         
sensual         
story           
tuck            
imperialist     
great           
excite          
east            
conclave        
beast           
calico          
beggar          
article         
enemy           
chuck           
critical        
ghost           
dispense        
figure          
algorithm       
bile            
handsome        
cat             
ivy             
impersonal      
pennant         
elephant        
glycerin        
ink             
squid           
pumpkin         
lexicon         
mediocrity      
meet            
alabaster       
morning         
calculator      
speaker         
pacify          
print           
condition       
popcorn         
spank           
moon            
quadrant        
earthquake      
revive          
sculpture       
misbehave       
skeleton        
ligament        
statute         
divisible       
document        
infant          
divot           
conspiracy      
bunt            
notice
```

Comment: To better answer your question, can you please post the content of the file

Comment: I've added in the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple program that have array of Strings. First we create counter and take sum of all String.leght() in given array. Then we create Array of char with that length and simply iterate and fill array.

```
public static void main(String []args){
        int index = 0;
        String[] ht = new String[3]; 
        int counter = 0;


        ht[0] = "Hello";
        ht[1] = "World";
        ht[2] = "Johm";

        for(int i = 0; i < ht.length; i++) {
                counter += ht[i].length();

        }
        char[] keyChar = new char[counter];

        for(int i = 0; i < ht.length; i++) {
            for  (int j = 0; j < ht[i].length(); j++) {
                keyChar[index] = ht[i].charAt(j);
                index++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(keyChar);
     }
```

This is solution for your problem.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File dataSet = new File("data.txt");
        Scanner fileRead = new Scanner(dataSet);
        int index = 0;
        int index2 = 0;
        int tableSize = 128;
        String[] ht = new String[tableSize];


        while (fileRead.hasNextLine() && index < ht.length) {
            ht[index] = fileRead.nextLine();
            index++;
        }

        int counter = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < ht.length; i++) {
            counter += ht[i].length();

        }
        char[] keyChar = new char[counter];

        for(int i = 0; i < ht.length; i++) {
            for  (int j = 0; j < ht[i].length(); j++) {
                keyChar[index2] = ht[i].charAt(j);
                index2++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(keyChar);



    }
```

Comment: That actually worked thank you! The only issue I'm getting now is that it only goes up to the 8th string from the array. I don't see any visible issues with it? It's only looping to 128 characters whereas the sum should be 2048.

Comment: @TaziamomaAbraham update your question with new code

Comment: I did, still getting the hang of this.

Comment: @TaziamomaAbraham I updated second part of answer specific for your code. I do not know what mistake you made I just created my code. If you find out what problem was please add it in your question at the bottom

Comment: it worked! My problem was my loop to print the charArray, I just had it set up wrong. I didn't I could just print the array like that and not have to loop it.

Comment: @TaziamomaAbraham oh I see. You can make my answer correct then

Answer (score 0):

Java Strings already have an inbuilt method to convert a String into an Array of Characters. Check out String.toCharArray().

---

You've created the char array with the same length as the String array. Char array length should be sum of lengths of all Strings.

Also, your nest for loop is wrong. Should be something like:

```
int charIndex = 0; // To keep track of char Array
for(int i = 0; i < ht.length; i++){ // Iterate over all Strings
        for(int j = 0; j < ht[i].length(); i++){
            keyChar[charIndex] = ht[i].charAt(j);
        }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using the charAt, I had originally tried to use the String.toCharArray() but I was getting a lot of complicated errors. And I fixed the loop, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The charAt() method returns the character at the specified index. Note that the index value should lie between 0 and length() - 1.

So if say a given index is equal to the length of the string i.e. length(), you'll get the `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.